# How to do a alias table

Tags: powershell

As we know, a `Cmtlet` maybe have a lot of alias,such as `copy,cp,cpi` always mean `Copy-Item`.So I want to make a alias table,it will like:

```
...
...
...
Copy-Item     copy,cp,cpi
Clear-Host    cls,clear
Move-Item     mi,move,mv
...
...
...
```

I can get all alias information use `(Get-Command -CommandType Alias).Definition|Get-Unique` to get the first column..But I don't know how to get the second colunm.

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? SU is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks for specify. I will do more research after post a question in this site.But anyway,I think the `Group-Object` can help me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it sorted and without curly braces::

```
Get-Alias | Sort Definition | Group-Object Definition|
  ForEach-Object{"{0,-30} {1}" -f $_.Name,(($_.group.name) -join(', ')) }
```

---

```
Add-Content                    ac
Add-PSSnapIn                   asnp
Clear-Content                  clc
Clear-History                  clhy
Clear-Host                     clear, cls
```

**Edit** A variant which returns a `[pscustomobject]` instead of a formatted string:

```
Get-Alias | Sort-Object Definition | Group-Object Definition | ForEach-Object{
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        CmdLet = $_.Name
        Aliases =(($_.group.name) -join(', '))
    }
}
```

---

```
CmdLet                         Aliases
------                         -------
Add-Content                    ac
Add-PSSnapIn                   asnp
Clear-Content                  clc
Clear-History                  clhy
Clear-Host                     clear, cls
```

Comment: I'm prefer a without curly braces version indeed,It is just little complicated..:)

Answer (score 1):

```
PS C:\> Get-Alias | Group-Object definition|ft name,group
```

will give what I'm after

```
Name                           Group
----                           -----
ForEach-Object                 {%, foreach}
Where-Object                   {?, where}
Add-Content                    {ac}
Add-PSSnapIn                   {asnp}
Get-Content                    {cat, gc, type}
Set-Location                   {cd, chdir, sl}
ConvertFrom-String             {CFS}
Clear-Content                  {clc}
Clear-Host                     {clear, cls}
Clear-History                  {clhy}
Clear-Item                     {cli}
Clear-ItemProperty             {clp}
Clear-Variable                 {clv}
Connect-PSSession              {cnsn}
Compare-Object                 {compare, diff}
...
```